# Exporting an image from QGIS for use in Autocad

Tags: qgis, autocad

I am using QGIS to open mrsid files from NAIP, clipping the part of the county that I need and using the "save as" option to export as a geotiff in state plane coordinates for use in Autocad.  I am having a few issues with this method:
First, the resolution on the image is not great.
Second, the insertion point comes into Autocad correctly but when I close the image correlation dialogue box the image rescales for some reason.

I can rescale the image, but am wondering what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to show the original, transformed image, or give a bit more detail.

Comment: It depends on CAD. Simplest way any of this family members understands is image rectangle shape, vector. Scale raster to opposite corners

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `Save As ...`, you can try `Raster -> Conversion -> Translate`. It allows you to rescale the output as well.

If you need a different coordinate system, you have to use `Raster -> Projections -> Warp`.

I'm not sure what units of measure Autocad uses, QGIS uses degrees, meters or feet, depending on the layer's CRS. You can create a custom CRS that uses other units if needed.